# Сборка проекта для .NET и .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, .net-core

При написании библиотеки, код которой валиден как для .NET Framework, так и для .NET Core, приходится создавать два разных проекта со своими зависимостями и *практически* одинаковым кодом.

Текущее положение дел *(необходимость отдельно обновлять код соседнего проекта и отдельно его собирать)* меня не очень устраивает. И пусть я написал скрипт для автоматизации этого, знаю, что есть решение получше. Можно как-то модифицировать сам проект в Visual Studio для достижения таковых целей:

- Возможность выбирать целевую платформу
- В зависимости от неё указывать символы в духе `NETCORE`, `NET` (по
  типу `DEBUG`), дабы в некоторых местах менять платформо-зависимый код
- В зависимости от неё использовать определённые пакеты

---

Как лучше организовать решение поставленной задачи?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/net-standard

Comment: @EvgeniyZ: сборка под `.NET Standart` не совсем то, что мне хотелось бы видеть. Я лучше обновлю вопрос)

Comment: Если Вы используете SDK based формат для файлов проекта (`.csproj`), то Вы можете указать несколько целевых платформ в параметре `TargetFrameworks`. Также можно указать атрибут `Condition` для зависимостей, чтобы они выбирались в зависимости от целевой платформы.

Comment: @PetSerAl: вот, именно то, что мне нужно. Попробую поискать по этой теме (никогда подобного не делал и до сих пор не удосужился разобраться с нутром `.csproj`... Позор на мою седую голову))

Comment: Вот простенький пример, как это можно сделать: https://gist.github.com/PetSerAl/53c469c4552370a9ca96db908295a805

Comment: @PetSerAl: спасибо огромное! Именно то, что я и имел в виду! Может, оформите ответом?)

Comment: М.б. кому-нибудь поможет
Организация проекта для параллельной поддержки .NET Framework и .NET Core
[ссылка](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/porting/project-structure)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

При использовании SDK based формата для файлов проекта (`.csproj`) можно указать несколько целевых платформ для сборки в элементе `TargetFrameworks`. Также можно использовать атрибут `Condition` для условного указания зависимостей.

`Test.csproj`:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <LangVersion>Latest</LangVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFrameworks>
      netcoreapp2.1;
      net472;
    </TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="$(Platform) == 'AnyCPU'">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework) == 'netcoreapp2.1'">
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="11.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework) == 'net472'">
    <PackageReference Include="System.Numerics.Vectors" Version="4.5.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

`Test.cs`:

```
using System;

namespace Test {
    class Program {
        static void Main() {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
#if NETFRAMEWORK
            Console.WriteLine(".NET Framework");
            Console.WriteLine((System.Numerics.Vector<byte>)new System.Numerics.Vector<int>(42));
#elif NETCOREAPP
            Console.WriteLine(".NET Core");
            Console.WriteLine(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { a = 1, b = 2 }));
#else
            Console.WriteLine("Unknown");
#endif
        }
    }
}
```

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/PetSerAl/53c469c4552370a9ca96db908295a805)

Answer (score 3):

> отдельно обновлять код соседнего проекта

у Вас две копии кода?

Положите cs файлы в третье место и добавьте их в оба проекта, используя опцию "Add As Link" в окне "Add Existing File".

Comment: В принципе, это решило бы проблему, если бы не буквально пара мест, которая все таки требует небольшой модификации от платформы к платформе. А лепить запутанные зависимости, где часть файлов прикреплена по ссылке, а другая - как обычный файл проекта... Но так идея вполне хорошая)

Comment: А `IFDEF` или аналога в сишарпе нету?

Comment: @Kromster: как раз есть - `#if ... #endif`. Вопрос больше в том, как это все организовать)

Comment: @Kir_Antipov если бы речь шла о Делфи, то были бы глобальные константы платформы (типа `IFDEF WINDOWS`) и константы задаваемые на уровне проекта (типа `IFDEF MY_PROJECT_2`).

Comment: @Kromster: я смотрю [документацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if), и там все же указано, что символы, определяющие платформу сборки, все таки в наличии есть. Осталось разобраться с тем, как нормально переключать сборку с одной платформы на другую, а также что делать с зависимостями ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Kir_Antipov "-Осталась последняя улика - пистолет. -Так эта улика, Володя, бьет сто тысяч других улик!" Место встречи изменить нельзя

Comment: @Igor: поддерживаю)